# EDIEL library for Java/C#

Tags: c#, java, edi

This is a long-shot but does anyone know of a library in Java/C# for handling the EDIEL specification (this is the EDI spec with extensions for electricity, used by scandanavian countries and a few others).

Failing that any resources with concrete examples of the messages in various scenarios?

Specifically I'm interested in the PRODAT/MSCONS/DELFOR/APERAK message types.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned something new, I've never heard of EDI in that field!
Here's a [site](http://www.ediel.no/EdielPortal/showDocument.aspx?url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.edisys.no%2fediel%2fBrukerveiledninger%2520og%2520Internformat.htm) that looks like the standards maker.  Unfortunately (for me, not for [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ediel.no%2FEdielPortal%2FshowDocument.aspx%3Furl%3Dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww.edisys.no%252fediel%252fBrukerveiledninger%252520og%252520Internformat.htm)) it's in Norwegian.  The first link on the left "Siste brukerveiledning" is a PDF for the latest manual with EDIel formatting and examples.

> "Norwegian Ediel-standard user-guide" is a merger of the former brukerveiledningene for APERAK, MSCONS and PRODAT plus UTILTS. The document describes the use of Ediel messages adapted to Norwegian framework conditions.

Google translates the site pretty well, but the PDF is another matter.  I recognized the EDI parts, but the explanations are a mystery.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the thing. A pretty new one: [EDIReader](http://edireader.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of is BizTalk 2009. It has a huge zip file (2xx MB) that contain numerous schema and a lot of EDI support. If it does not have the schema you need you can write your own schema or check if you can buy or get the schema somewhere from other companies that are also using BizTalk for their EDI interfaces.